# parallel calls in hibernate and PL/SQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im using Spring MVC with spring hibernate(2.5.6) and Hibernate core(3.3.2GA). As part of request processing application making calls to DB (both PL/SQL calls and normal HQL calls).

Issues(Deadlock/Unique key Constraint Violation) relies with modification of table where update/delete operations are invoked from hibernate and also from PL/SQL. It occurs while system takes maximum load. Can any one of you provide the your views to control the transaction management from data source?

Im using below configuration in spring bean XML.

Comment: How are you invoking PL/SQL and is it in a separate connection and/or transaction?

Comment: invoking through named queries. like this.getSession().getNamedQuery("QueryName");

Comment: And also like this.getSession().createSQLQuery("schema.package");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the solution, but not sure whether this works or not. if we setting the below properties as transaction attributes  then  spring transaction management will take care of dead locks transaction. It will not occur.

PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, -DeadlockLoserDataAccessException
PROPAGATION_REQUIRED